# Subset column names with specific string

Tags: r, regex, subset, grepl

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on column names starting with a particular string. I have some columns which are like ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 and some like ABC_XYZ_1, ABC_XYZ_2, ABC_XYZ_3

How can I subset my dataframe such that it contains only ABC_1, ABC_2, ABC_3 ...ABC_n columns and not the ABC_XYZ_1, ABC_XYZ_2...?

I have tried this option

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( ABC_1 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            ABC_2 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            ABC_XYZ_1 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            ABC_XYZ_2 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE) )


df1 <- df[ , grepl( "ABC" , names( df ) ) ]

ind <- apply( df1 , 1 , function(x) any( x > 0 ) )

df1[ ind , ]
```

but this gives me both the column names with ABC_1...ABC_n ...and ABC_XYZ_1...ABC_XYZ_n... I am not interested in ABC_XYZ_1 columns , only columns with ABC_1,.... Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specify "ABC_" followed by a one or more digits (i.e. `\\d+` or `[0-9]+`), you can use

```
df1 <- df[ , grepl("ABC_\\d+", names( df ), perl = TRUE ) ]
# df1 <- df[ , grepl("ABC_[0-9]+", names( df ), perl = TRUE ) ] # another option
```

To force the column names to start with "ABC_" you can add `^` to the regex to match only when "ABC_\d+" occurs at the start of the string as opposed to occurring anywhere within it.

```
df1 <- df[ , grepl("^ABC_\\d+", names( df ), perl = TRUE ) ]
```

---

If `dplyr` is more to your liking, you might try

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, matches("^ABC_\\d+"))
```

Comment: maybe even "^ABC_\\d+"

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward solution would be using `substr` :

```
df1 <- df[,substr(names(df),5,7) != 'XYZ']
```